# How do I make an operator with specific permissions?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

In Minecraft I want to make my friends operators but I don't want them to be able to run all the commands a operator can run. For example, say I make my friend an operator and now they can use / commands, I don't want them to be able to /kill but I still want for them to be able to use /fill. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of now, this is not possible in Minecraft Education Edition.

You could perhaps create some custom items such as splash potions with name tags and through the use of command blocks and the execute command build command "items" which could then be given to users.

Comment: That's helpful, how about in java?